# Stored Proc and WCF Data Services

Tags: sql, wcf

I've got a WCF Data Service setup and can access the table data through the browser url.

Have created a simple Stored Proc which takes in a parameter and then returns some columns from various tables via Joins - how can I consume this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an Entity Framework model you could do this:

1. Open the Model Browser.
2. Right-click "EntityContainer: (name)"-> "Function Imports" and select "Add Function Import...".
3. Select stored procedure, specify "Complex" as "Returns a Collection Of", click "Get Column Information" and click "Create New Complex Type". [image]
4. Add `config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("SomeStoredProcedure", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);` to the InitializeService method in SomeDataService.svc.cs.
5. Now add a method with the WebGet attribute to SomeDataService.svc.cs that returns an IQueryable of the complex type you defined previously:

`[WebGet]
    public IQueryable<SomeStoredProcedure_Result> SomeStoredProcedure()
    {
      return CurrentDataSource.SomeStoredProcedure(1).AsQueryable();
    }`

The 1 above is a parameter to the stored procedure.

The stored procedure can now be consumed at:

```
http://localhost/SomeDataService.svc/SomeStoredProcedure
```

Comment: @Martin4Andersen Is there an example in SOF or elsewhere, for calling a Stored Proc that updates or deletes?